# std::array filling using std::fill vs std::integer_sequence

Tags: c++, templates

I don't really have any problems, I am just curious a little. I've been browsing SO and saw [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58535982/pack-expansion-for-stdarray-initialization-using-stdindex-sequence) post. It is a pretty cool trick but does it offer any advantages over a plain old std::fill?

I've been playing around with it in the quick bench and it seems that it doesn't offer any advantages in terms of performance with both -Og and -O3 and obviously it doesn't help with readability. I just can't think of any reason to ever use it. I am a newbie in c++ and maybe I did something wrong so here is my code for fill version:

```
template<typename T, size_t N, typename... Ts>
auto make_fill_array(Ts&&... args) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T>::value)
    -> std::array<T, N> {
    std::array<T, N> ret;
    std::fill(ret.begin(), ret.end(), T{std::forward<Ts>(args)...});
    return ret;
}
```

Also there is a template specialization for containers that are constructible with std::initializer_list but that's just some boilerplate.

Edit:
I was asked about usage. I didn't really think this code through because it isn't part of my personal projects, it is just personal curiosity so my tests were simple stuff like this.

```
auto fillarray = make_fill_array<Point, 10>(1, 6);
```

or

```
auto fillarray2 = make_fill_array<std::vector<Point>, 5>(5, Point{1, 6});
```

Comment: First use whatever is *correct*. Second use whatever is most readable. If all equal, use whatever performs best.

Comment: Your version requires a copyable `T`.  The other constructs each `T` instance independently from its constructor arguments.

Comment: Your fill version doesn't seem correct a number of ways. How would you use that?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I already found out that it won't work for non default constructible and non copy assignable. But what other ways my code is broken? It worked well while I tested it with pod and std containers.

Comment: @suspiciously_large_carrot Perhaps you could add the code you used when testing the function so the usage becomes clear.

Comment: @TedLyngmo added edit.

Comment: @suspiciously_large_carrot Aha, got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a lot more of `T` than the pack-expansion solution.

If the type is not default constructible, `std::array<T, N> ret;` won't work (at least, for `N > 0`).

And if it's not copy assignable, then the `fill` won't work either. (Also `std::array` has a `fill` member function.)

And finally, if it's not move constructible, then `return ret;` won't work.

Comment: Hmmm it makes sense. But I don't get the last point, why would it need move? It usually would just be NRVOed, and even if NRVO won't kick in, won't it just copy?